# Evaluate the sum $ 22\binom{26}{0} + 21\binom{26}{1} + 20\binom{26}{2} + \cdots + (-3)\binom{26}{25} + (-4)\binom{26}{26}. $

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Evaluate the sum
$$22\binom{26}{0} + 21\binom{26}{1} + 20\binom{26}{2} + \cdots + (-3)\binom{26}{25} + (-4)\binom{26}{26}.$$

---

Is there an obvious shortcut I'm missing?  I know I can't just do the whole calculation!  That would take years!  But I don't see another way.  Solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: $22=26-4$, $21=25-4$, .. can you proceed from here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: ${n \choose m}={n\choose n-m}$.
Edit: Note that this should be easy to show both combinatorially and algebraically.

Comment: I got $697585176,$ is that correct?

Comment: @Regina Using my hint, we can rewrite this expression so that each binomial coefficient has a coefficient of $9$. This is because for $i<13$, we have $(22-i){26 \choose i}$ and $(-4+i){26 \choose {26-i}}$ which we can sum to $(18){26 \choose i}$, and then redistribute it again into $9{26 \choose i}+9{26 \choose 26-i}$ by using the hint again. For $i=13$, we have only the term $9{26\choose 13}$. This gives us $9\sum_{i=0}^{26} {26\choose i}$. What does that sum represent combinatorially if you ignore the $9$?

Comment: Is the answer $9 \cdot 2^{26}$?

Comment: @Regina That's right!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{26}\pars{22 - k}{26 \choose k} & =
22\sum_{k = 0}^{26}{26 \choose k} -
\left.\partiald{}{x}\sum_{k = 0}^{26}{26 \choose k}x^{k}\,\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 1}
=
22 \times 2^{26} - \left.\partiald{\pars{1 + x}^{26}}{x}\,\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 1}
\\[5mm] & =
22 \times 2^{26} - 26 \times 2^{25} = 22 \times 2^{26} - 13 \times 2^{26} =
\color{#f00}{9 \times 2^{26}}
\end{align}